# Another question on the procedure of majorization

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I know I already asked a question about majorizations, but trust me when I say I really need to get this. Please don't whip me too much.

Let's say I need to prove that the function $$ f(x, y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^6+y^4}{x^2+y^2} & (x, y) \neq (0, 0) \\\\ 0 & (x, y) = (0, 0)\end{cases}$$

is continuous at the origin.

I have to stick to the distance method, hence a majorzation that leads me to conclude that $$|f(x, y) - f(0, 0)| \leq \phi(d)$$

where $\phi(d) \to 0$ as $d\to 0$, a function of a distance (or norm).

Here again is where I struggle in understanding how to operate. I mean look at this: I can either do:

$$\bigg|\frac{x^6+y^4}{x^2+y^2}\bigg| = \frac{x^6+y^4}{x^2+y^2} \leq \frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2} = 1$$

(since I am near the origin, then $x^6 < x^2$ and so on), or I can have this

$$\bigg|\frac{x^6+y^4}{x^2+y^2}\bigg| = \frac{x^6+y^4}{x^2+y^2} \leq \frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2} \to 0$$

Or also other things like

$$\bigg|\frac{x^6+y^4}{x^2+y^2}\bigg| = \frac{x^6+y^4}{x^2+y^2} \leq \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} \to +\infty$$

I still struggle in understanding how to operate. I know that it's like a very stupid question, shame on me. I just need a little push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have any bound of the form $f(x,y) \le g(x,y)$, and you know $g(x,y)\to 0$, you are done, because all you want to show is continuity at the origin.

All the estimates you gave, in the forms of upper bounds are true, but some are stronger than others. For example, you identified that as $x,y\to 0$, $x^6\le x^3$ and $y^4 \le y^3$, so one bound you can show is $f(x,y)\le (x^3 + y^3)/(x^2 + y^2)$. This bound is enough to show $f(x,y)\to 0$. And it's a stronger estimate than saying $f(x,y) \le 1$, which isn't sufficient for your purpose.

To summarize, there isn't a single correct estimate, but rather there are sufficient and insufficient estimates. $f(x,y)\le (x^3+y^3)/(x^2+y^2)$ is sufficient, while $f(x,y)\le 1/(x^2+y^2)$ and $f(x,y)\le 1$ are insufficient.

---

To be sure an estimate is sufficient for your purpose, you will have to give a proof that it is sufficient. For example, let's work with the cubic estimate. In the typical $\epsilon,\delta$-framework, we are given $\epsilon$, and need to provide a $\delta$ so that if $|(x,y)|<\delta$, $f(x,y)<\epsilon$. The aim is to use our cubic estimate to facilitate this. So here it goes.

Suppose $|(x,y)|<\delta$, for some $\delta$ to be determined later. Then $x<\delta$ and $y < \delta$, so we have
$$
f(x,y) \le \frac{x^3 + y^3}{x^2 + y^2} \le  \delta\frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2 + y^2} = \delta.
$$
We used our cubic estimate in the first inequality, and the assumption that $|(x,y)|\le \delta$ in the second inequality. Now it's evident that if we take $\delta = \epsilon$, $f(x,y) < \epsilon$  provided $|(x,y)|<\delta$. By the definition of limit in terms of $\epsilon,\delta$, $f(x,y)\to 0$ as $(x,y)\to 0$.

This is the only justification that our estimate "works"!

Comment: That was so clear, finally! Thank you so much!! Just another question: how can I be sure about the estimation I pick? If, to say, I picked a wrong one I could commit the error to say that $f(x, y)$ is not continuous at the origin, whilst it is...

Comment: @Numb3rs: Good question. I updated my answer to address it. The short answer is that the only way you can be sure is to prove it! Your intuition about which estimates will work is an important step, but to be sure we really have to give a proof, don't we?

Comment: Thank you so much!! Indeed our professor only taught the distance method, to call it so. He never taught us the epsilon-delta proof (and he doesn't want us to use it), and this clearly made LOTS of questions to arise... Finally I understood that what he did not teach us, is what does actually provide the real proof haha /sigh...

Comment: @Numb3rs: I would say that in some cases, a proof doesn't need to involve $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, but invoking them is almost certainly the most flexible approach.

Comment: @Numb3rs: One more thing I have to add is that an estimate in the form of an upper bound can never "prove" that $f$ is not continuous at the origin for problems like these. A bound of the form $f(x,y) \le 1$, for example only says that $f$ is bounded near $0$. This doesn't contradict continuity at the origin because it is just saying something weaker. It's "insufficient" in the language I used in my post. To prove the limit doesn't exist at the origin, we would have to provide some concrete sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ so that $f(x_n,y_n)$ does not converge to $0$.

Comment: Thank you again! I know I'm becoming annoying but in the case of the proof via sequences, how can one "guess" the right sequence? :D (if existent)

Comment: @Numb3rs: Intuition or guessing + trial and error (which builds intuition).